# Problema con javamail

Tags: java, android, gmail, email

Tengo una app creada y una opción consiste en enviar un formulario en background usando javamail, el problema es que a la hora de añadir una imagen, la aplicación actúa como si enviase el mail correctamente pero en la bandeja de Gmail no recibo nada. Sin embargo, si envío el mismo email pero sin añadir una imagen adjunta si recibo perfectamente el correo. He mirado en mil sitios pero no encuentro la solucion al problema. Adjunto el código completo.

```
public class Correo extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener{

//Declaring EditText
private EditText editTextSubject;
private EditText editTextMessage;
private EditText editTextNombre;
private EditText editTextApellidos;
private EditText editTextTelefono;
/*public static final String Nombre = "NomKey";
public static final String Apellidos = "ApKey";
public static final String Asunto = "AsKey";
public static final String Mensaje = "MenKey";
public static final String Telefono = "TelKey";
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";*/

Button btnTackPic;
ImageView ivThumbnailPhoto;
Bitmap bitMap;
static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;
Button btngal;
String rutaimg;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;

//Send button
private Button buttonSend;
Button btnUbicacion;
String ubicacion;
double latitud = 0;
double longitud = 0;
EditText editubi;

Bitmap bitimg;
File imagefile;
BodyPart adjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.correo);


    //Initializing the views
    editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    editTextNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
    editTextApellidos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextApellidos);
    editTextTelefono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefono);
    editubi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editubi);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    btnUbicacion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUbicacion);

    //Adding click listener
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    });
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

    }
    btnUbicacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getLocation();
    }

    });;




    btnTackPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
    ivThumbnailPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailPhoto);

    // add onclick listener to the button
    btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            // start camera activity
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    btngal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngal) ;

    btngal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent!=null){
        // get bundle
        bitMap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
        ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMap);

    }

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri = intent.getData();
        imagefile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));

        ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageURI(imageUri);

        try {
            bitimg = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private void openGallery(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}


private void sendEmail() {
    //Getting content for email
    String email = "**********@gmail.com";
    String subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    String nombre = editTextNombre.getText().toString().trim();
    String apellidos = editTextApellidos.getText().toString().trim();
    String telefono = editTextTelefono.getText().toString().trim();
    String ubiman = editubi.getText().toString().trim();

    String msg = "Nombre: " + nombre + " " + apellidos + "\n" + "\n" + "Teléfono: " + telefono + "\n" + "\n" + "Asunto: " + subject + "\n" + "\n" + "Incidencia: " + message + "\n" + "\n" + "Ubicación manual : " + ubiman + "\n" + "\n" + "Ubicación GPS: " + ubicacion + "\n" + "\n" ;


    /*if (subject.equals("") || message.equals("") || nombre.equals("") || apellidos.equals("") || telefono.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, rellene todos los campos marcados con asterisco", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{*/
        //Creating SendMail object
        SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, msg, imagefile);

        //Executing sendmail to send email

        sm.execute();
        editTextMessage.setText("");
        editTextSubject.setText("");
        editTextTelefono.setText("");
        editTextApellidos.setText("");
        editTextNombre.setText("");
    //}

}
void getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5,  this);
    }
    catch(SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitud = location.getLatitude();
    longitud = location.getLongitude();
    ubicacion = "https://maps.google.com?q=" + latitud + "," + longitud;
    if (latitud != 0 || longitud != 0) {
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    latitud, longitud, 1);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                editubi.setText(DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(Correo.this, "Active el GPS y el Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: //hago un case por si en un futuro agrego mas opciones
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Atrás!");
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

El archivo de imagen lo envío a la clase SendMail, donde se recibe perfectamente:

```
 public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>  {

//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;

//Information to send email
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;
//private MimeMultipart Adjunto = new MimeMultipart();
private File imagefile;

//private BodyPart adjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
//private BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();



//Progressdialog to show while sending email
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Intent intent;

//Class Constructor
public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message, File imagefile){
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
    this.imagefile = imagefile;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //Showing progress dialog while sending email
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Enviando incidencia","Espere...",false,false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Dismissing the progress dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //Showing a success message
    Toast.makeText(context,"Incidencia enviada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Creating properties
    Properties props = new Properties();

    //Configuring properties for gmail
    //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "***********@gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                }
            });


    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);

        mm.setText(message);

        MimeBodyPart at = new MimeBodyPart();
        at.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
        at.attachFile(imagefile);
        at.setFileName("incidencia.jpg");

        //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(at);

        //Adding message
        mm.setContent(multipart);

        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect(Config.EMAIL,Config.PASSWORD);
        t.sendMessage(mm,mm.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();
        //Sending email
        //Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para poder ayudarte necesitamos más informacion. Tienes logs o has hecho depuración para ver qué puede estar sucediendo? Mira [ask] para mejorar la informacion de la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Has verificado que la imagen se está obteniendo correctamente aquí: `imagefile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));`?

Comment: En principio si, al pasar el modo depuración obtiene correctamente la ruta de la imagen y se pasa bien en el método SendMail @A.Cedano